# Understanding State Reassignment in BZ2_decompress Function of bzip2

Tags: c

I am currently working with the refactoring `bzip2` [decompression function](https://gitlab.com/bzip2/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.c?ref_type=heads#L197) from C to Rust and encountered a particular piece of code in the `BZ2_decompress` function that has left me puzzled. This function is part of the `decompress.i` file, which I obtained after using the `save-temps` option during compilation of bzip2.

The code below is [a snippet from decompress.i](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.i?ref_type=heads#L3052) involves a switch-case statement handling different states within the decompression process. I noticed that in this statement, specifically from `case 10` till `case 50`, after each case is detected, the state is explicitly set to the same value it just matched. For example:

```c
switch (s->state) {
  case 10:
    s->state = 10;
    // ... (other code)
}
```

Here is [the complete code snippet from decompress.i from case 10 till case 50](https://gitlab.com/SheldonHH/bzip2/-/blob/master/decompress.i?ref_type=heads#L3052) .

I am trying to understand the rationale behind this pattern. Why is it necessary to explicitly set `s->state` to the same value it just checked against? Is this a common practice in certain scenarios, or does it serve a specific purpose in the context of the `BZ2_decompress` function?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated, as I am keen to understand the best practices and subtleties involved in handling such cases in C programming.

Comment: There is a fallthrough, so this could also be from the previous state (or before it).

Comment: As @ChayimFriedman already said the `switch` statement in C requires a `break` to leave it, or the execution will proceed with next `case` . In the code if the conditions in the last case's `if` is verified the execution branches to the exit part, else it proceed with next case incrementing appropriately the code status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fallthrough, so the state value could also be of the previous state (or before it). This resets it to the value of this state, so when we will enter the `switch` at the next time we will go immediately to the state where we left.

I guess the first `case` doesn't really need this, and it's left there because all other cases have it.

Comment: still a bit confusing, since case already match for example case 15, means `s->state = =15`, why we still need to set `s->state = 15`

Answer (score 1):

In C programming, sometimes `switch-case` statement where the `state` value **set inside a case is the same as the value it matches**, just as in the code snippet you mentioned. This might be due to the "fallthrough" feature of switch-case statements, where if a break statement is not explicitly used to terminate the case, the structure will continue executing until a break is encountered or the switch structure ends.

Imagine we have a state machine that performs different operations based on different states. Sometimes, we want to ensure that each time we enter the switch-case structure, the current state value is clear. By setting the state value inside each case, even if a fallthrough occurs, we can ensure that the state value is what we expect.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int state = 10;
    
    switch (state) {
        case 10:
            printf("Processing state 10\n");
            // There might be a lot of logic here...
            // To simplify, let's jump to state 20
            state = 20;
            // No break here, execution continues
        case 20:
            state = 20; // Ensuring the state value is correct
            printf("Current state is 20\n");
            // Processing logic for state 20...
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown state\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, even though we change the state to 20 in case 10, we explicitly set the state again in case 20. This is done for clarity and consistency, even though in this simple example, the state setting in case 20 seems redundant. In complex state machines or larger switch-case structures, this practice can prevent state errors caused by code modifications, especially during maintenance.

## more complex example involve loop to set `state` value inside a case is the same as the value it matches

Here, the explicit setting of the `state` within the case block ensures that when we re-enter the loop, the `state` is set correctly regardless of any fallthrough that may occur.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int state = 10;
    int event = 0;
    int continueProcessing = 1;

    while (continueProcessing) {
        printf("Handling event %d\n", event);

        switch (state) {
            case 10:
                // Event processing for state 10...
                printf("Starting in state 10\n");
                if (event == 1) {
                    state = 20; // Transition to state 20 based on event
                }
                // Intentional fallthrough to share some logic with state 20

            case 20:
                state = 20; // Ensure the state is set to 20 even after fallthrough
                // Shared or specific event processing for state 20...
                printf("Now in state 20\n");
                if (event == 2) {
                    state = 30; // Transition to state 30 based on event
                } else {
                    continueProcessing = 0; // Stop processing
                }
                break;

            case 30:
                // State 30 specific processing...
                printf("Transitioning to state 30\n");
                continueProcessing = 0; // Stop processing after state 30
                break;

            default:
                printf("Unknown state\n");
                continueProcessing = 0; // Stop processing on unknown state
        }

        event++; // Move to the next event
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, we have a while loop that iterates over events. Depending on the event, the state may change. The state is explicitly set in the `case 20` block, which is crucial after a fallthrough from case 10. Without setting `state = 20` inside `case 20`, if the event `== 1` condition was true in `case 10`, and we had some shared logic that should only run when the state is exactly 20, we might erroneously run that logic with a state of 10. By setting `state = 20`, we prevent such errors.

Moreover, it's also a way to maintain the state consistency when the same case block might be reached through different paths. This example is simplistic, but in a real-world scenario, especially where the states and events are numerous and more complex, such explicit state setting becomes even more critical to maintain the program's correctness.